# Converting Dataframe Object into Date Python

Tags: python, date, object, dataframe, casting

A python dataframe 'dff' containing data imported from SAS is having a date field whose type is showing as below by python:

```
dff.effvdate.head()
Out[47]: 
0    b'09JUL2013'
1    b'17OCT2013'
2    b'03MAR2014'
3    b'08MAY2014'
4    b'10MAR2015'
Name: effvdate, dtype: object
```

I am trying to convert this date to datetype as below:

```
dff['REPORT_MONTH'] =[dt.datetime.strptime(d,"%d%b%Y").date() for d in dff['effvdate']]
```

showing this error

```
TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not bytes
```

As i am new to python, need help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error `TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not bytes` gives you the information you need to know!  `d` is in bytes, not a string.  you should cast d to string.

```
dff['REPORT_MONTH'] =[dt.datetime.strptime(d.decode('UTF-8'),"%d%b%Y").date() for d in dff['effvdate']]
```

should work.

see [What does the 'b' character do in front of a string literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269765/what-does-the-b-character-do-in-front-of-a-string-literal)

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works. But when I save this date in my dataframe still it shows it as 'object', Why?. What actually 'object' is?

Comment: an object is a thing that has attributes.  which is basically everything in python.

Comment: you have a dataframe object, which itself contains date objects

Comment: OK. Got it. its a class object having attribute and possibly some functions. Thanks a lot.

Comment: you should accept the answer if you found it solved your problem.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know as I a new user of this forum I didnt know about this. I hope I did it correctly.